# Read a huge text document in python

Tags: python

I have a 16GB text document file with the following structure:

```
name1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 
...
...
nameN 1 1 1 0 1 0 -1 1 0 1
```

I want to be able to do the following processing to the file:

```
my_dict = {}

for line in data.split("\n"):
    cells = line.split()
    my_dict[cells[0]] = [int(x) for x in cells[1:]]
```

The problem is that if I open the file by:

```
open(data) as f: 
    content = f.readlines()
```

I get:

> 'list' object has no attribute 'split'.

Is there any way to open the file to be able to do the above processing?

Comment: Are you sure you want to load the entire 16 GB into one `dict`? This will require more than 16 GB of memory. If so, Ananths answer should give you the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `f.readlines()` gives you a list of strings representing the lines. It already does the splitting by `"\n"`, so when you are trying to do the processing, do it without splitting by the newline character:

```
my_dict = {}

for line in content:
    cells = line.split()
    my_dict[cells[0]] = [int(x) for x in cells[1:]]
```

Answer (score 2):

the nicest way to do that is by

```
with open(data) as f:
    for line in f:
        cells = line.strip().split()
        # do something
```

this way you do not hold your 16GB data multiple times in memory (python 2 and python 3). you should also try to avoid holding the complete dict.